# Wanted: photoshop filter for free-hand glyph to simulate anti-aliasing

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typography, anti-aliasing

I want to draw a letterform free-hand, simulating an aliased character and I would like to then apply a filter so it looks like an anti-aliased character *[ed. note: simulate sub-pixel rendering?]*.

I tried the various blur filters but the blur is too regular. Is there a filter that would make it look more like a real anti-aliased letterform?

**edit : since you need it it here is an exemple of a letter I would like to make look like a rasterized anti-aliased letter** : [image: rasterization]

link : http://s24.postimg.org/g3c9eaq4h/manual_rasterization.png

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's completely unclear what it is you are seeking or trying to do. Your explanation is severely lacking.

Comment: what's unclear in drawing a letter with pen tool pixel by pixel then applying a filter to it to make it look like a rasterized caracter ?

Comment: Because drawing a letter pixel by pixel **is** raster. If you are drawing the pixels, you're drawing the raster output. Your sample "G" will look identical in raster or vector form. The only difference is scaling functionality. Are you certain you know what "raster" means???

Comment: i got no idea what it means but I would love to find a filter that does what i need, i uploaded a new example with R the first one is aliased and the second one is anti-aliased

Comment: I reopened this. There was no need for that last edit. Clicking "flag" and explaining is a better course to take.

Comment: That previous edit only makes the question more opaque: are you asking how to automatically turn a hand-drawn letter into a perfect letterform? Is this a question about handwriting recognition?

Comment: not at all I just want to be able to create letters that look like other ones without me having the name of the font nor the font. For instance I have the anti-aliased **R** and I would like to make the letter **H** that would be from the same font as **R** without me knowing the name of the font. But I can visually recognize what characteristics of the font are. The bilinear softening reduce or the blur effect works to some extent but maybe there are filters that would do exactly what I need ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Photoshop's `Filter > Pixelate > Mosaic..` and a *low* "cell size" may be what you are after. I'm really just guessing here without seeing sample images.

.. and I have *no clue* what "real rasterized character" means. If it's pixel-based art, it's already raster. I don't think there is such a thing as "fake" raster.

[image]

### **Edit: this filter works on type too. It isn't restricted to using a specific source.**

Comment: this doesn't work when the caracters are too small (less than 10*10 pixels, takes at least a radius of 2 and the letter become unreadable)

Comment: Because at 10x10 you've got 10 pixels to work with. If you already drew the letter at that size, "pixel by pixel" as you've stated, then you have *exactly* what the raster output would be. Raster is pixel-based. If you draw the pixels, you draw the raster appearance. There's something lacking in your explanation. Not sure what it is, but you're essentially stating "I drew a blue square. How to do I now make my square blue?"

Comment: Draw your letter 8 times larger then, and *then* apply this filter.

Comment: I want a pixel by pixel drawn letter that is aliased to look like a letter that has been typed with a wordpad or word or photoshop text editor. I'm basically looking for a filter that would give my letters the same appearance as if it had been typed in a text editor. Do you know if such thing exists ? You can check the updated pictur I put, in the left side there is my pencil drawn letter R and in the left side is the letter typed from a text editor that has been captured from a screen print.

Comment: You are looking to anti-alias something without any need for anti-aliasing. As @Jongware points out, draw larger and reduce to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A picture would really help here, but if the goal is to make it look like the 8-bit era of video gaming, you don't want a filter, but rather simply reduce the resolution of your image drastically.

But note that that is not how most 8-bit art is created. Most of it is drawn pixel-by-pixel to best accommodate the low resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little tough to understand. When you say character, do you mean you're hand-drawing letters? Or you're drawing a portrait of a character, like for a video game?

From what I understand so far, it sounds like you used the pencil tool to draw a picture, and now you want to make the image look like it was drawn with smoother tools, like a brush.

If that's the case, you'd probably be best off re-drawing it with a different tool, or outlining it as a vector.

If it's a grayscale image without transparency, like hand-drawn letters or outlines, you can sometimes get away with blurring it with any tool (the Gaussian blur filter is handy) and then reducing it back down using either contrast/curves/levels or the unsharp mask filter. This doesn't lead to a natural look for artwork though.